# Basic vertical SVG line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I cannot seem to find a good, working example / tutorial of how to draw a simple, vertical line which animates gradually on scroll from nothing to a full line.

I have the code below which draws a horizontal line, but I cannot seem to successfully change this to a vertical line that continues to animate.

HTML:

```
<svg id="mySVG">
    <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="triangle" d="M1 0 L75 0"/>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 210px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
    // Get the id of the <path> element and the length of <path>
    var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
    var length = triangle.getTotalLength();

   // The start position of the drawing
   triangle.style.strokeDasharray = length;

   // Hide the triangle by offsetting dash. Remove this line to show the             triangle before scroll draw
   triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  // Find scroll percentage on scroll (using cross-browser properties), and offset dash same amount as percentage scrolled
  window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
      var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop +      document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -    document.documentElement.clientHeight);

      var draw = length * scrollpercent;

     // Reverse the drawing (when scrolling upwards)
     triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You want to do it only with svg? I think it would be easier with css3

Comment: @Roysh - is this possible with animation?

Comment: with transition. yes

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/80288oko/1/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

thanks for all your replies - I ended up using CSS transitions as this seem to work better.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of making your line vertical, as follows:

```
<svg id="mySVG">
  <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="triangle" d="M1 0 L1 75"/>
</svg>
```

What happens when you do that?